# System apps missing after QR provisioning

Tags: android, device-admin, device-owner

I'm trying to provision my 7.0 device through QR provisioning. The provisioning was done successfully but it created a separate profile and the apps in the priv-app section are not visible here.

When i try to manually install the apps through adb it says success but the app is still not visible. On checking the apps section in settings it says that the app is installed on another user.

Any idea on how to get those system apps into the current provisioned profile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the extra [`EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED) to `true` in your QR code bundle:

```
{
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED": true
}
```

Comment: @NivilBoban Where you have set this flag? In the device policy? I have added it in the generated QR code but it's not getting scanned.

Comment: You can use my qr code for reference :

{"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "packagename/packagename.AdminReceiver", "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM": "your checksum", "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "apk url", "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED":true,"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_SKIP_ENCRYPTION":true,"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE":{"license":"test" } }

Comment: Please make sure that there are no spaces between each field in the qr